# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dllAdditional information

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlexception

I'm new to C# and windows form. I am still a learner.

In the following code, I am getting `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` at `int Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
this issue also states:

> Procedure or function Patient_Users_operation has too many arguments specified

```cs
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        string Gender;
        String Chkbox;
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void rdoBtnMale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Gender = "M";
        }

        private void rdoBtnFemale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Gender = "F";
        }
        private void drpboxType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void chkActive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkActive.Checked)
            {
                Chkbox = "ACTIVE";
            }
            else
            {
                Chkbox = "INACTIVE";
            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txtName.Text=="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter your name");
                txtName.Focus();
            }
            else if(txtMobile.Text=="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter your Mobile Number");
                txtMobile.Focus();
            }
            else if(!Regex.IsMatch(txtMobile.Text, @"^[0-9]{10}$"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Correct Mobile Number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtMobile.Focus();
            }
            else if(txtEmail.Text=="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Email id");
                txtEmail.Focus();
            }
            else if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid Email id", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtEmail.Focus();
            }
            else if(!rdoBtnMale.Checked && !rdoBtnFemale.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Gender");
                lblGender.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =JITENDER-KAUSHI\SQLSERVER; Initial Catalog = Patient ; Integrated Security = True");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Patient_Users_operation", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SP_User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Duplicate";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMobile.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Gender;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = drpboxType.SelectedItem;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Chkbox;
                conn.Open();
                int DuplicateRecord = Convert.ToInt32( cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                conn.Close();
                if (DuplicateRecord == 0)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SP_User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SAVE";
                    conn.Open();
                    int Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//0---Operation Not Successfull,1-Successfull
                    conn.Close();
                    if (Result == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved Successfully");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Record Not Saved Successfully", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Record Found");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

The following snippet is the SQL Stored Procedure

```
Create Proc [dbo].[Patient_Users_operation]
(
            @SP_User    VARCHAR(100),
            @Name       VARCHAR(50)=NULL,
            @Mobile     VARCHAR(15)=NULL,
            @Email      VARCHAR(50)=NULL,
            @Gender     CHAR=NULL,
            @Address    VARCHAR(500)=NULL, 
            @Type       VARCHAR(10)=NULL, 
            @Status     VARCHAR(10)=NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
        IF(@SP_User='SAVE')
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Patient_Data 
                (
                            Name,
                            Mobile,
                            Email,
                            Gender,
                            Address,
                            Type,
                            Status 
                )
                Values      
                (
                            @Name,
                            @Mobile,
                            @Email,
                            @Gender,
                            @Address, 
                            @Type, 
                            @Status
                );
            END
            ELSE IF(@SP_User='UPDATE')
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE Patient_Data
                        SET
                            Name=@Name,
                            Mobile=@Mobile,
                            Email=@Email,
                            Gender=@Gender,
                            Address=@Address,
                            Type=@Type,
                            Status=@Status
                END
            ELSE IF(@SP_User='DELETE')
                BEGIN
                    DELETE FROM Patient_Data
                        WHERE 
                            Name=@Name
                        AND
                            Mobile=@Mobile
                        AND
                            Email=@Email
                        AND
                            Gender=@Gender
                        AND
                            Address=@Address
                        AND
                            Type=@Type
                        AND
                            Status=@Status
                END
END
```

Comment: You didn't post the StoredProcedure, which is what the error is about. Check the parameters.

Comment: Looks like you are adding drpboxType.SelectedItem as a parameter which is of type object and needs to be cast to it's intended value as such: (string)drpboxType.SelectedItem

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I shared the StoredProcedure

Comment: You are also declaring the Gender param as VarChar but it is of type Char is the procedure.  You should also set the length in the procedure (@Gender     CHAR(1)=NULL,)

Answer (score 1):

This error will come because I used 9 parameters but at the time of defined only 8 in sp.
I Use `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` for solving this problem.
look at below code for more

```
`if (DuplicateRecord == 0)
 {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SP_User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SAVE";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =txtName.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMobile.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.Char).Value = Gender;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (string)drpboxType.SelectedItem;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Chkbox;
                    conn.Open();
                    int Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//0---Operation Not Successfull,1-Successfull
                    conn.Close();
                    if (Result == 1)`
```